# $Y=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x=0\text{ or } y=0\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. What is the interior of $C=\{(x,0):-1<x<1\}$ in the subspace $Y$.

Tags: general-topology

> $Y=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x=0\text{ or } y=0\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard topology. What is the interior of $C=\{(x,0):-1<x<1\}$ in the subspace $Y$

I believe it is $A=\{(x,0): -1<x<0\}\cup\{ (x,0): 0<x<1)\}$

I think it's clear that $A\subseteq int(C)$ since it is the union of $2$ open sets in $Y$ contained in $C$. But I'm not sure how to show that $int(C)\subseteq A$.

Comment: Note that $\operatorname{int}(C)\subseteq C=A\cup\left\{(0,0)\right\}$. If you can show that $(0,0)\not\in\operatorname{int}(C)$, then you can conclude that $\operatorname{int}(C)\subseteq A$.

Comment: @K.K.McDonald $Y$ is definitely a subspace of the topological space $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. You are describing the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ in which case you are right that $Y$ is not a (linear) subspace.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro I think I see. If an open set contains $(0,0)$ then it must contain the intersection of an open ball $B_\epsilon(0,0)\cap Y$ for some $\epsilon>0$ which clearly contains elements not in $C$.

Comment: @AColoredReptile Yes. Details apart, that's the core of the question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing my mistake @Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is show that $(0,0)$ is *not* an interior point, i.e., that it has no neighborhood (in $Y$) contained in $C$. But what does every neighborhood of $(0,0)$ (in $Y$) look like?